# Why 'javac' produces two methods with same name/parameters but different return types for generics?

Tags: generics, jvm, javac

This is the example.

```
class ParentReturnType {}
class ChildReturnType extends ParentReturnType {}
class Parent {
  ParentReturnType foo() {...}
}
class Child<R extends ChildReturnType> extends Parent {
  @Override
  R foo() {...}
}
```

For class `Child`, `javac` produces two methods named `foo`:

1. the first `foo()` returns `ChildReturnType`, whose body is what we defined in `Child.foo()`
2. the second `foo()` returns `ParentReturnType`, which simply calls the first `foo()`

I don't quite understand why `javac` produces two versions of `foo()`.

I believe one version of `foo()` that returns `ParentReturnType` with its body defined in `R foo()`(in the source code) would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the JVM, unlike the Java language includes the return type as part of the identity of a method.

Thus in Java it is not possible to override a method by return type (it has to be by input args). However in the JVM world it is legal to do so.

The last piece of the jigsaw is that Java identifies which JVM signature to invoke at compile time and not at runtime. Thus it is the compiler that identifies which of these methods should be invoked, and back when generics were added to java a design goal was to minimise changes to the runtime. That is, as much was done at the compiler stage as possible and so while other solutions that do not involve generating two methods could be envisioned it was pragmatic to do so given the tools already available and the time scales.